# Boto3 S3: Get files without getting folders

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

Using boto3, how can I retrieve all files in my S3 bucket without retrieving the folders?

Consider the following file structure:

```
file_1.txt
folder_1/
    file_2.txt
    file_3.txt
    folder_2/
        folder_3/
            file_4.txt
```

In this example Im only interested in the 4 files.

**EDIT:**

A manual solution is:

```
def count_files_in_folder(prefix):
    total = 0
    keys = s3_client.list_objects(Bucket=bucket_name, Prefix=prefix)
    for key in keys['Contents']:
        if key['Key'][-1:] != '/':
            total += 1
    return total
```

In this case total would be 4.

If I just did

```
count = len(s3_client.list_objects(Bucket=bucket_name, Prefix=prefix))
```

the result would be 7 objects (4 files and 3 folders):

```
file.txt
folder_1/
folder_1/file_2.txt
folder_1/file_3.txt
folder_1/folder_2/
folder_1/folder_2/folder_3/
folder_1/folder_2/folder_3/file_4.txt
```

I JUST want:

```
file.txt
folder_1/file_2.txt
folder_1/file_3.txt  
folder_1/folder_2/folder_3/file_4.txt
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

S3 is an OBJECT STORE. It DOES NOT store file/object under directories tree. 
New comer always confuse the "folder" option given by them, which in fact an arbitrary prefix for the object.

object `PREFIX` is a way to retrieve your object organised by predefined fix file name(key) prefix structure, e.g. .

You can imagine using a file system that don't allow you to create a directory, but allow you to create file name with a slash "/" or backslash "\" as delimiter, and you can denote "level" of the file by a common prefix.

Thus in S3, you can use following to "simulate directory" that is not a directory.

```
folder1-folder2-folder3-myobject
folder1/folder2/folder3/myobject
folder1\folder2\folder3\myobject
```

As you can see, object name can store inside S3 regardless what kind of arbitrary folder separator(delimiter)  you use.

However, to help user to make bulks file transfer to S3, tools such as aws cli, s3_transfer api attempt to simplify the step and create object name follow your input local folder structure.

So if you are sure that all the S3 object is using `/` or `\` as separator , you can use tools like S3transfer or AWSCcli to make a simple download by using the key name.

Here is the quick and dirty code using the resource iterator. Using s3.resource.object.filter will return iterator that doesn't have same 1000 keys limit as list_objects()/list_objects_v2().

```
import os 
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
mybucket = s3.Bucket("mybucket")
# if blank prefix is given, return everything)
bucket_prefix="/some/prefix/here"
objs = mybucket.objects.filter(
    Prefix = bucket_prefix)

for obj in objs:
    path, filename = os.path.split(obj.key)
    # boto3 s3 download_file will throw exception if folder not exists
    try:
        os.makedirs(path) 
    except FileExistsError:
        pass
    mybucket.download_file(obj.key, obj.key)
```

Comment: Explaining downvote: This does not really address the question and quite honestly I'm a bit confused why this is accepted instead of one of the answers below that actually help with filtering out these unwanted items. The "folders are not really folders" thing is good btw-info, but has little practical impact here. The point also gets muddied if even the AWS console and documentation themselves call them "folders" and treat them that way.

Answer (score 14):

There are no folders in S3.  What you have is four files named:

```
file_1.txt
folder_1/file_2.txt
folder_1/file_3.txt
folder_1/folder_2/folder_3/file_4.txt
```

Those are the actual names of the objects in S3.  If what you want is to end up with:

```
file_1.txt
file_2.txt
file_3.txt
file_4.txt
```

all sitting in the same directory on a local file system you would need to manipulate the name of the object to strip out just the file name.  Something like this would work:

```
import os.path

full_name = 'folder_1/folder_2/folder_3/file_4.txt'
file_name = os.path.basename(full_name)
```

The variable `file_name` would then contain `'file_4.txt'`.

Comment: Well, in S3 there actually are "folders", they are represented as a key with an appending slash. Folders also have a Size of zero and look like a folder in AWS S3 web console GUI. 
So what I basically want to know is if its possible to sort out Keys with their name ending with a slash. Preferable this should not be done manually (if possible)

Comment: No, there really are no folders in S3.  If you perform a ``ListObjects`` API request of your bucket, all you will see are the four file names listed above.  S3 allows you to specify the delimiter ("/" by default) and it will then allow you to navigate the objects as if there were folders but there is no object stored in S3 that represents the folder ``folder1``.  There is no way to tell the S3 service to only return the base filenames.  You would have to get a listing of all objects and then manipulate the object names to extract just the base file name.

Comment: No sir, a list_objects would return 7 objects
http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects

Comment: You could use the ``Prefix`` parameter when listing objects in your bucket to get it to only return the objects within a particular virtual folder.  Perhaps that would help? If you pass a ``Prefix=folder_1/folder_2/folder_3/`` when you list objects, S3 will only return ``file_4.txt``.

Comment: @Vingtoft those aren't folders, those are 0 byte files that some tool has created to mimic the creation of folders in your S3 bucket.

Comment: @garnaat this is a good answer but it needs some sort of duplicate file name handling. If `folder1/file.txt` and `folder2/file.txt` existed, when you saved both to the same local directory one would overwrite the other.

Comment: @garnaat correct me if I'm wrong, but are folders in an operating system not exactly the same? Well, my conclusion is there is no way to retrieve files without retrieving "folders". Thanks

Comment: @MarkB I agree.  I'm not sure I totally understand the OP's goal.  If there are duplicate file names in different hierarchies (or even the chance of that happening) handling duplicates becomes very important.

Comment: @Vingtoft folders in your OS file system are required to exist before you can place a file in that folder. In S3 not only is the folder not required to exist, but there is no link between "folder" and the file. If you are getting 7 objects when you try to download from S3 then you have used some sort of S3 tool that created those fake "folders" in your S3 bucket, using 0 byte files. Those 0 byte objects in your S3 bucket are not required and don't need to exist at all.

Comment: @Vingtoft In a Linux filesystem, a directory is a first class element represented by an inode just like a file.  In S3, there is no server-side entity called a folder.  There are only objects in a flat namespace.  The delimiter ("/" by default) can be used to give the illusion of a hierarchical name space.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the clarification. 
Perhaps folders does not exist in S3, but they sure do when I call a list_objects. I have created the folder using the "Create Folder" button on the aws.amazon.com/s3 console.

Comment: Im really confused about folders not existing in S3, because (as I just said) a big button on the console creates folders, I retrieve folders when I call a list_objects. But you a right, I have red multiple times in S3 documentation that folders does not exist. Then how come they exists as zero size objects?!

Comment: I downvoted because this does not address the actual question and instead discusses the technicality whether S3 "folders" are folders or not (which, btw, even the AWS web console calls folders), which is ultimately not helpful. The problem is that the list_objects call will return these "folders" or prefixes or whatever you wanna call them as items that look the same as actual files, which causes problems if you want to do any operation on every file in a bucket. For this, btomtom5's, airborne's and estani's answers are a lot more helpful, yet for some reason have fewer votes.

Comment: I downvoted, because this answer is wrong. The results of `os.path.basename` depend on the operating system you are working on. But the path of S3 is always going to have `/ ` separators. Hence, the use of the separators defined by the OS is just wrong. It only happens to work by accident as long as the OS uses the same separator as S3.

Answer (score 13):

One way to filter out folders is by checking the end character of the Object if you are certain that no files end in a forward slash:

```
for object_summary in objects.all():
    if object_summary.key[-1] == "/":
        continue
```

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the other answers, s3 does not actually have directories trees. But there is a convenient workaround taking advantage of the fact that the s3 "folders" have zero size by using paginators. This code-snippet will print out the desired output if all your files in the bucket have size > 0 (of course you need to adapt your region) :

```
bucket_name = "bucketname"
s3 = boto3.client('s3', region_name='eu-central-1')
paginator = s3.get_paginator('list_objects')
[print(page['Key']) for page in paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket_name).search("Contents[?Size > `0`][]")]
```

The filtering is done using [JMESPath](https://jmespath.org/).

Note: Of course this would also exclude files with size 0, but usually you don't need storage for empty files.

Answer (score 3):

Using `v2` you also get the size of the file, so you can filter the keys.

```
s3_client
  .list_objects_v2(bucket: bucket_name, prefix: prefix)
  .select { |e| e[:size] > 0 }
  .map { |e| e[:key] }
```

Answer (score 0):

Following up on @airborne answer, you can use JMESPath to filter all keys that end with a \

This will still return empty files but will filter out all none file keys (unless you have a file name that ends with \ which will force you to try to get the content to make sure it is a file).

```python
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def count_files_in_folder(bucket_name: str prefix: str) -> int:
    paginator = s3.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
    result = paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket_name, Prefix=prefix).search("Contents[? !ends_with(key, '/')]")
    return len(result)
```

This will return all the keys without any pagination.

Answer (score 0):

```
This is a way to get the count of files only in a bucket without counting the folders.

    import boto3
    
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    
    def search_files_in_bucket(event, context):
      
      count = 0
      response = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket='name_of_bucket')
     
      if 'Contents' in response:
        for object in response['Contents']:
          #count += 1
      #print(count)
          if object['Key'][-1] != '/':
            count += 1
      return(count)

Paginate:
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def search_files_in_bucket(event, context):
  
  count = 0
  response = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=event['bucket'])
  paginator = s3.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
  response_iterator = paginator.paginate(Bucket=event['bucket'])
  filtered_iterator = response_iterator.search('Contents[?Size > `100`][]')
  
  if 'Contents' in response:
    for object in response['Contents']:
      if object['Key'][-1] != '/':
        for key_data in filtered_iterator:
          count += 1
  return("Number of files: ", count)
```