# Download specific folder and all of its files recursively from S3 bitbucket using boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto, boto3

I know how to download files recursively using aws cli

```
aws s3 cp {s3Directory} {localDirectory} --recursive
```

But i want to use Python Boto and below is my code. I want to download folders and all of its files ('Daily/2017/02/15/') from bucket 'news-live'. When i execute below command, all folders created but there is no file downloaded.

```
def main():
DOWNLOAD_LOCATION_PATH = "/Users/test/"
BUCKET_NAME = 'news-live'
conn  = boto.connect_s3(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_ACCESS_SECRET_KEY)
bucket = conn.get_bucket(BUCKET_NAME)

#goto through the list of files
bucket_list = bucket.list('Daily/2017/02/15/')

for l in bucket_list:
    key_string = str(l.key)
    print("bucket key", l.key)
    s3_path = DOWNLOAD_LOCATION_PATH + key_string
    try:
        print ("Current File is ", s3_path)
        l.get_contents_to_filename(s3_path)
    except (OSError,S3ResponseError) as e:
        pass
        # check if the file has been downloaded locally  
        if not os.path.exists(s3_path):
            try:
                os.makedirs(s3_path)
            except OSError as exc:
                # let guard againts race conditions
                import errno
                if exc.errno != errno.EEXIST:
                    raise
```

I don't know how to get this work.

Comment: Similar question has been ask many time. Checkout answer from this question on how to do it using boto3.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42673764/boto3-s3-get-files-without-getting-folders/42691511#42691511

Comment: You can find the answer over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13063474/downloading-the-files-from-s3-recursively-using-boto-python